# Beginner help with Arrays & Complexity

Tags: algorithms, arrays, algorithm-design

My goal is to create a method that gets an array that only has 1's and 0's in it, and then turns every number into the amount of 'steps' it is away from the closest 0, left or right.

So for example [1] - [1] - [0] - [1] - [1] - [1] - [1] - [1] - [0] - [1]  would be
[2] - [1] - [0] - [1] - [2] - [3] - [2] - [1] - [0] - [1]

I also need to do it as simple as possible in terms of time and space complexity.

I'm not sure how to make it count how far a certain spot is from a 0 if it's from the right of the 0, or if there's another 0 nearby I'm not sure how to make it count which one is closest.

I'm assuming two for loops are needed?

Made a sketch: no idea if it makes sense.

```
 for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{

    for (int j=i; j<a.length; j++)
    {
     if (a[j]==0)
      {
       if (i<j)
         {
           a[i]=j-i;
         }
        if(j<i)
         {  
           a[i]=i-j;
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @Raphael It's actually O(n). two loops are not nested. (And I didn't want to give this info because it seems like OP is already almost on to it.)

Comment: All I see are some loops. Try to explain in words how you think you should proceed. The steps are: Understanding the problem. Figuring out how to solve it. Writing code. You left out the most important middle step.

Comment: And two loops in the way you are using them are not needed. The problem can be solved easily in linear time.

Comment: Since j starts at i then j cannot be < i

Comment: Jup, that's the brute-force solution. Try to be smarter! (Also, bug: how can `j < i` ever be true?)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to solve a simpler problem first:

**Given an array that only has 1's and 0's in it, the method turns every number into the amount of 'steps' it is away from the closest 0 to the left.**

Now this problem is easy. A simple solution is: traverse the array from left to right, keeping track of the distance from the last zero encountered and updating each element with the distance.

A simple code:

```
dist = INF
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(a[i] == 0)
       dist = 0;
    else
       dist++;
    b[i] = dist;
}
```

Now once you have solved the simpler problem for closest 0 to the left, you can similarly solve the problem for closest 0 to the right. With these two solutions, you should be able to easily get a solution for the original problem (by taking a min of the two solutions).

The solution evidently has O(n) time complexity, and can be easily coded to use only O(1) space by carefully manipulating the updates in the original array only.

Answer (score 2):

Just some hints that will tell you how to solve it efficiently:

If you know where the first zero is, then you know what numbers to write down at all positions before and up to that zero. For example, if a [4] is the first zero, then you know the numbers for positions 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 (4, 3, 2, 1, 0). You don't know the number for position 5 at this point.

If you know where two consecutive zeroes are, then you know what numbers to write down at all positions from the first to the second of these two zeroes. For example, if there is a zero at a [4] and the next zero is at a [9] then you know all the numbers for positions 4 to 9 (0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0).

And if you know the position of the last zero, then you know what numbers to write down at all positions from that zero to the end of the array.

Comment: I think that's an overly complicated idea.

Answer (score -2):

Just iterate in each direction and track the distance from the last zero

You could get fancier with some back tracking to only go one direction but would not be much faster

2n is still O(n)

lastZero is the distance from the last zero

```
int[] result  //this store the answer / calculation 
int lastZero = null
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if(input[i] = 0)
    {
        lastZero = 0
        result[i] = 0
    }
    else if (lastZero != null)
    {
        lastZero++
        result[i] = lastZero
    }
}
//now go from right to left  
lastZero = null
for(i = len - 1; i <= 0; i--)
{
    if(input[i] = 0)
    {
        lastZero = 0
    }
    else if (lastZero != null)
    {
        lastZero++
        if(result[i] > lastZero or result[i] = null) 
           result[i] = lastZero
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again, we're looking for explanation, not code dumps.

Comment: @BDriz Input is your input array.   Result is the array of results (calculation).

Comment: @Paparazzi No, I never claimed that it didn't work. That's now _twice_ that you've mischaracterized [what I said about that answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48668/find-minimum-number-of-platforms/69411#comment148473_69411).

Comment: @DavidRicherby  So does not answer the question is different than does not work.  Question "Calculate the maximum number of trains that would be present in the platform at any given time".   That is what my answer does.   I asked you if you had any questions.

Comment: @Paparazzi A set of truths does not make a good answer. A single block of code certainly does not.

Comment: @Raphael What do you want?  To me  "just iterate in each direction and track the distance from the last zero" is a blue collar way of explaining exactly what needs to happen.

Comment: @Paparazzi This seems to be your fundamental misunderstanding. The question was not "calculate X" but "HOW can I calculate X?" How many times do we have to tell you? We're looking for explanations, not code.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am not trying to be difficult but in my little mind "Just iterate in each direction and track the distance from the last zero" is explaining exactly how to calculate.

Comment: It's okay if you write a block of code that solves it and there's an explanation attached. I'm just trying to learn and now I'm going through the logic of it.